# Rspec test of the object method call in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I want to test that a controller create and update actions call a process method on the MentionService instance.

In controller I have MentionService.new(post).process

This is my current spec:

```
it "calls MentionService if a post has been submitted" do
  post = Post.new(new_post_params)
  mention_service = MentionService.new(post)
  expect(mention_service).to receive(:process)
  xhr(:post, :create, company_id: company.id, remark: new_post_params)
end
```

In the controller actions I have:

```
def create
  ...
  # after save
  MentionService.new(@remark).process
  ...
end
```

What I get is:

```
expected: 1 time with any arguments
received: 0 times with any arguments
```

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: can you also show us the controller code  ?

Comment: I added the controller snippet.

Comment: the MentionService instance in your test is not the same one as the one in your controller. The one in your test isn't receiving `process` - the one in your controller is.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you're creating a new instance in your test and expect that instance to receive `:process` which will not work.

Try playing around with this snippet:

```
let(:service) { double(:service) }

it "calls MentionService if a post has been submitted" do
  expect(MentionService).to receive(:new).with(post).and_return(service)
  expect(service).to receive(:process)
  xhr(:post, :create, company_id: company.id, remark: new_post_params)
end
```

You need to tell your `MentionService` class to receive `:new` and return a mock object, which will receive `:process`. If that is the case, you know the call sequence succeeded.

Comment: Thanks, this looks good. However, xhr creates a remark/post with a new ID. But first expect `expect(MentionService).to receive(:new).with(post).and_return(service)` is before the xhr so it assigns a post w/o the ID. So there is `received :new with unexpected arguments` : one post with NIL id vs one post with the ID.

Comment: you can leave out the `.with(post)` part and just check whether it recieves the call to new, not caring about the parameters.

Comment: Works like a charm. Cool. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 3):

If you're not interested with supplying the mock object yourself you can also modify your expectation to:

```
expect_any_instance_of(MentionService).to receive(:process)
```